# Google Drive is saying "Sorry, Backup and Sync needs to quit."?

Tags: google-drive

I'm using Google Drive privately. Since today, I'm receiving the following error message on my computer:

> **Sorry, Backup and Sync needs to quit.**
>
> Something went wrong. Backup and Sync needs to quit.
>
> Error: Backup and Sync is disabled for this account. Please email uploader-eng@ from your google.com account if you need a personal account whitelisted..

[image: Google Backup and Sync Error]

[image: Google Backup and Sync Error]

Since I'm not alowed to post to the "uploader-eng" group as the error sugests, I cannot really contact them.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Contact Google Support. FWIW, I uninstalled Google Backup and Sync then reinstalled Google Drive. This resolved the "issue".

Comment: OP could you include the text "Something went wrong. Backup and Sync needs to quit. Error: Backup and Sync is disabled for this account. Please email uploader-eng@ from your google.com account if you need a personal account whitelisted.." from the error to help google route people to this thread?

Comment: I noticed there were two separate installs on my computer ( windows 10 ) one had the traditional google drive icon, the other looked like a cloud. I uninstalled both of them and deleted the entire contents of my google drive. I then re-installed google drive and it is currently syncing. Will update post sync whether that solved the problem.

Comment: @Xzila I'm guessing that unless they've removed the software from the auto-update source, when the software goes to auto-update it may get the bad version again. Then again, hopefully that was one of the first things Google did to mitigate the problem.

Comment: @Xzila I updated the title to have the error message text

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**UPDATE: March 16, 2017 4:22:00 PM PDT**

*This will be the last update I post here from the RSS feed unless some other significant information is posted.*

> The problem with Google Drive should be resolved. We apologize for the
>   inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support.
>
> The Windows client will automatically update with this fixed version
>   within the next 10 hours. Alternatively, affected users can download
>   the updated version of the client from
>   https://www.google.com/drive/download/. Affected Windows 10 users may
>   be required to sign in to their Google account within the client.

**UPDATE from Google March 16, 2017 2:58:00 PM PDT:**

*Includes official repair information*

> Google Drive service has already been restored for some users, and we
>   expect a resolution for all users within the next 12 hours. Please
>   note this time frame is an estimate and may change.
>
> We are deploying an updated client now. The Windows client will
>   automatically update with this fixed version within the next 12 hours.
>   Alternatively, affected users can download the updated version of the
>   client from https://www.google.com/drive/download/. Affected Windows
>   10 users may be required to sign in to their Google account within the
>   client.

*This is the latest update. There are more updates at the RSS link below.*

**This appears to be a rather widespread issue**: https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/5zrwwp/google_drive_is_now_backup_and_sync_error/

Google may have released an internal build of a new version of Google Drive/Backup and Sync by mistake.

We can assume they're aware of this and are working to resolve the issue. In the meantime, if the uninstall/reinstall suggestions of other answers do not resolve the issue, just wait a bit.

**Google themselves have also released a notice**: https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=d9bab8e4a0fdfb97d4ac42a2c918af14

> > 3/16/17, 11:41 AM    We're aware of a problem with Google Drive affecting a significant subset of users. The affected users are able
> >     to access Google Drive, but are seeing error messages and/or other
> >     unexpected behavior. We will provide an update by 3/16/17, 12:41 PM
> >     detailing when we expect to resolve the problem. Please note that this
> >     resolution time is an estimate and may change. Some users of the
> >     Google Drive Sync client will be receiving the error message "Sorry,
> >     Backup and Sync needs to quit."
>
> We have identified the root cause of the issue and are implementing a
>   potential fix now.

**If you wish to receive notice of the resolution quickly**

Here's an RSS feed for the Google Drive application status: https://www.google.com/appsstatus/rss/en

**The Google Product Forums will be updated as the issue progresses as well:**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/Km-e-xRJ9b4;context-place=forum/drive

Comment: I successfully re-installed. Would be nice if I didn't have to do that on my other computers. Does anyone know how to trigger the roll-back/fix update? Has anyone's problems been resolved via update rather than re-install?

Comment: Even after the update, it's showing the same error. Accessing behind a corporate proxy.

Comment: @AbuAbdullah What is the name of the program currently installed? Is it Google Drive, or is it Google Backup and Sync?

Comment: @music2myear It appears google had retracted Backup & Sync. Just download google drive setup and it got installed as Drive.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused by Google.

They released a Status message under [the Google Drive Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=d9bab8e4a0fdfb97d4ac42a2c918af14):

> We're aware of a problem with Google Drive affecting a significant
>   subset of users. The affected users are able to access Google Drive,
>   but are seeing error messages and/or other unexpected behavior. We
>   will provide an update by 3/16/17, 8:41 PM detailing when we expect to
>   resolve the problem. Please note that this resolution time is an
>   estimate and may change. Some users of the Google Drive Sync client
>   will be receiving the error message "Sorry, Backup and Sync needs to
>   quit."
>
> We have identified the root cause of the issue and are implementing a
>   potential fix now.

Update on the Issue:

> Our team is continuing to investigate this issue. We will provide an
>   update by 3/16/17, 9:29 PM with more information about this problem.
>   Thank you for your patience. Some users of the Google Drive Sync
>   client for Windows will receive the error message "Sorry, Backup and
>   Sync needs to quit" and will be unable to use the client. Other Sync
>   clients are not affected. Affected users may continue using the Google
>   Drive web interface and mobile applications.
>
> We have identified the root cause of the issue and are implementing a
>   potential fix now.

Comment: Source: https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=4&iid=d9bab8e4a0fdfb97d4ac42a2c918af14

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling google drive worked for me. I did uninstall via revouninstaller (portable), deleted reg keys and folders, that revo found, reboot. Downloaded from google drive installer and voila. Now it is google drive triangle icon, not blue cloud google backup and sync.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to *Programs and features*
- Uninstall *Google Drive* **AND** *Google Backup and Sync* if listed (my PC had these two apps installed)
- Reboot
- Go to your online Google Drive.
- Download Google Drive and install.

This worked for me.

Comment: In my case, I tried to install _Drive_ without first uninstalling _Backup and Sync_, after which _Drive_ didn't work anymore. I eventually could fix it by renaming (deleting should also work) the `%localappdata%\Google\Drive` folder.